# Inserting records into an sql database using loops

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sqlite

Hi Please Help with this code! The code gets information from text boxes on another page which is all done correctly, its then passed through a function and the results are saved as variables. I am trying to insert records into a database for each day missing weekends, for the length of a certain time period, $StartDate to $EndDate. Thanks any help would be appreciated.

```
<?php
session_start();

//Extract user data
$SelectedRoom = $_POST['Room'];
$Period1 = cleanString(trim($_POST['Period1']));
$Period2 = cleanString(trim($_POST['Period2']));
$Morning_Break =  cleanString(trim($_POST['Morning_Break']));
$Period3 = cleanString(trim($_POST['Period3']));
$Period4 = cleanString(trim($_POST['Period4']));
$Period5 = cleanString(trim($_POST['Period5']));
$Lunch1 = cleanString(trim($_POST['Lunch1']));
$Lunch2 = cleanString(trim($_POST['Lunch2']));
$Period6 = cleanString(trim($_POST['Period6']));
$Period7 = cleanString(trim($_POST['Period7']));
$Period8 = cleanString(trim($_POST['Period8']));




// create or open database called TimeTable.sqlite
$db = @sqlite_open("TimeTable.sqlite");
//Get Start Date from table
$sql = "SELECT fldStartDate FROM tblTermDate WHERE fldTerm_Name ='Christmas 1st Half'";
$res = sqlite_query($db, $sql);
if (sqlite_num_rows($res) > 0) {
    $StartDate = sqlite_fetch_single($res);
}
//Get End Date from Table
$sql = "SELECT fldEndDate FROM tblTermDate WHERE fldTerm_Name ='Christmas 1st Half'";
$res = sqlite_query($db, $sql);
if (sqlite_num_rows($res) > 0) {
    $EndDate = sqlite_fetch_single($res);   
}
// Finds the differnce between the days
$Days = (strtotime($EndDate) - strtotime($StartDate)) / 86400;
echo $Days;
if($db) {
    for($count = 0; $count = $Days; $count++) {
        // insert new booking
        for($counter = 1; $counter = 5; $counter++) {
            @sqlite_exec($db, "INSERT INTO tblBooking(fldRoom_ID, fldPeriod_ID, fldDate, fldBooking_Name, fldStaff_ID, fldComment) VALUES('" . $SelectedRoom . "',' Period_1 ','" . $StartDate . "','" . $Period1 . "',' '', '')");

            @sqlite_exec($db, "INSERT INTO tblBooking(fldRoom_ID, fldPeriod_ID, fldDate, fldBooking_Name, fldStaff_ID, fldComment) VALUES('" . $SelectedRoom . "',' Period_2 ','" . $StartDate . "','" . $Period2 . "',' '', '')");

            @sqlite_exec($db, "INSERT INTO tblBooking(fldRoom_ID, fldPeriod_ID, fldDate, fldBooking_Name, fldStaff_ID, fldComment) VALUES('" . $SelectedRoom . "',' Morning_Break ','" . $StartDate . "','" . $Morning_Break . "',' '', '')");

            @sqlite_exec($db, "INSERT INTO tblBooking(fldRoom_ID, fldPeriod_ID, fldDate, fldBooking_Name, fldStaff_ID, fldComment) VALUES('" . $SelectedRoom . "',' Period_3 ','" . $StartDate . "','" . $Period3 . "',' '', '')");

            @sqlite_exec($db, "INSERT INTO tblBooking(fldRoom_ID, fldPeriod_ID, fldDate, fldBooking_Name, fldStaff_ID, fldComment) VALUES('" . $SelectedRoom . "',' Period_4 ','" . $StartDate . "','" . $Period4 . "',' '', '')");

            @sqlite_exec($db, "INSERT INTO tblBooking(fldRoom_ID, fldPeriod_ID, fldDate, fldBooking_Name, fldStaff_ID, fldComment) VALUES('" . $SelectedRoom . "',' Period_5 ','" . $StartDate . "','" . $Period5 . "',' '', '')");

            @sqlite_exec($db, "INSERT INTO tblBooking(fldRoom_ID, fldPeriod_ID, fldDate, fldBooking_Name, fldStaff_ID, fldComment) VALUES('" . $SelectedRoom . "',' Lunch_1 ','" . $StartDate . "','" . $Lunch1 . "',' '', '')");

            @sqlite_exec($db, "INSERT INTO tblBooking(fldRoom_ID, fldPeriod_ID, fldDate, fldBooking_Name, fldStaff_ID, fldComment) VALUES('" . $SelectedRoom . "',' Lunch_2 ','" . $StartDate . "','" . $Lunch2 . "',' '', '')");

            @sqlite_exec($db, "INSERT INTO tblBooking(fldRoom_ID, fldPeriod_ID, fldDate, fldBooking_Name, fldStaff_ID, fldComment) VALUES('" . $SelectedRoom . "',' Period_6 ','" . $StartDate . "','" . $Period6 . "',' '', '')");

            @sqlite_exec($db, "INSERT INTO tblBooking(fldRoom_ID, fldPeriod_ID, fldDate, fldBooking_Name, fldStaff_ID, fldComment) VALUES('" . $SelectedRoom . "',' Period_7 ','" . $StartDate . "','" . $Period7 . "',' '', '')");

            @sqlite_exec($db, "INSERT INTO tblBooking(fldRoom_ID, fldPeriod_ID, fldDate, fldBooking_Name, fldStaff_ID, fldComment) VALUES('" . $SelectedRoom . "',' Period_8 ','" . $StartDate . "','" . $Period8 . "',' '', '')");

            $StartDate = strtotime($StartDate) + 86400;
        }
        $StartDate = strtotime($StartDate) + 172800;
        $count = $count + 2;
    }
    $_SESSION['WeeklyMessage'] = "Monday TimeTable Changed";
}
else {
    $_SESSION['WeeklyMessage'] = "Monday TimeTable Not Changed Error";
}
// close connection
@sqlite_close($db);

//return to previous webpage with message sent as session variable
header("Location: admin.php");

?>
```

Comment: Try removing all your error suppression. (The @)

Comment: just for your information, with php, if you name an input field like `Period[1] Period[2]` etc, you'll have an easy to use array instead of multiple distinct items

Comment: Just FYI, you should be able to get both your period start and period end with a single SELECT query.  Also you should be able to bulk insert all your records with a single query, just build query's insert values in loop and execute a single insert.

Comment: I would recommend you learn about and use prepared statements with bindings.  This will allow you to re-execute the same query with different data and has the added benefit of being the best way to prevent SQL injection.  You will not need to pass all your string data through cleanString(), etc.  http://www.php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.prepare.php

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `$counter > 5` and `$count  > $Days` in a `for` loop instead of `=`

```
  for($count = 0; $count = $Days; $count++) {
    // insert new booking
    for($counter = 1; $counter = 5; $counter++) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Tweaking what user876345 said, You need to use `$counter <= 5` and `$count <= $Days` in a for loop instead of `=`

```
for($count = 0; $count <= $Days; $count++) {
    // insert new booking
    for($counter = 1; $counter <= 5; $counter++) {
```